# Resampling with Deedle duplicate keys

Tags: c#, deedle

My code below resamples 5-minute interval to 1-day interval for the daily profit stats. The problem is that BacktestResult consists of duplicate CloseDate values, because I'm testing with multiple pairs (TRXUSDT, ETHUSDT and BTCUSDT). `dailyProfit` returns `Series<DateTime, double>`, which explains the exception. How can I make it grouped by Pair or something? It works fine when tested with one pair.

```cs
// Create series
var series = _backtestResults.ToOrdinalSeries();

// daily_profit = results.resample('1d', on = 'close_date')['profit_percent'].sum()
var dailyProfit = series.ResampleEquivalence(
    index => new DateTime(series[index].CloseDate.Year, series[index].CloseDate.Month, series[index].CloseDate.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    group => group.SelectValues(g => g.ProfitPercentage).Sum()).DropMissing();

// classes
public class BacktestResult
{
    public string Pair { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitAbs { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal TradeDuration { get; set; }
    public SellType SellReason { get; set; }
}
```

#### Edit:

Example which takes the JSON data from pastebin:

```cs
using Deedle;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace Resample
{
    class Program
    {
        public class BacktestResultTest
        {
            public string Pair { get; set; }
            public decimal ProfitPercentage { get; set; }
            public decimal ProfitAbs { get; set; }
            public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }
            public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }
            public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime CloseDate { get; set; }
            public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
            public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
            public decimal TradeDuration { get; set; }
            public bool OpenAtEnd { get; set; }
            public int SellReason { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Take JSON data from pastebin
            using var webClient = new WebClient();
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/Dhp9202f");

            // Deserialize the data
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BacktestResultTest>>(json);

            var ts = data.ToOrdinalSeries();

            var byDateAndPair = ts.SelectKeys(kvp => Tuple.Create(kvp.Value.Value.CloseDate, kvp.Value.Value.Pair)).SortByKey();

            // daily_profit = results.resample('1d', on = 'close_date')['profit_percent'].sum()
            var dailyProfit2 = byDateAndPair.ResampleEquivalence(
                k => Tuple.Create(new DateTime(k.Item1.Year, k.Item1.Month, k.Item1.Day), k.Item2),
                g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.ProfitPercentage).Sum());

            // backtest_worst_day = min(daily_profit)
            var worstDay2 = dailyProfit2.Min();
            // backtest_best_day = max(daily_profit)
            var bestDay2 = dailyProfit2.Max();
            // winning_days = sum(daily_profit > 0)
            var winningDays2 = dailyProfit2.SelectValues(x => x > 0).Sum();
            // draw_days = sum(daily_profit == 0)
            var drawDays2 = dailyProfit2.SelectValues(x => x == 0).Sum();
            // losing_days = sum(daily_profit < 0)
            var losingDays2 = dailyProfit2.SelectValues(x => x < 0).Sum();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom data type as a key in Deedle. If you want to be able to use resampling on the series, then this needs to support `IComparable`. You can either define your own type or use built-in `Tuple`.

Assuming we have some very basic data:

```
var ts =
  new[] {
    KeyValue.Create(new DateTime(2020,1,1), new { Value = 1.0, Kind = "A" }),
    KeyValue.Create(new DateTime(2020,1,2), new { Value = 1.0, Kind = "A" }),
    KeyValue.Create(new DateTime(2020,1,3), new { Value = 1.0, Kind = "B" }),
    KeyValue.Create(new DateTime(2020,1,4), new { Value = 1.0, Kind = "B" }),
    }.ToSeries();
```

The first thing we need to do is to change the key to be the date together with a kind. (In fact, you can get into trouble earlier in your code if you had duplicate dates!)

```
var byDateAndKind =
  ts.SelectKeys(kvp => Tuple.Create(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Value.Kind)).SortByKey();
```

Now the key is `Tuple<DateTime, string>` consisting of the date and the kind. You can now use `ResampleEquivalence` on this. Here, we use year and kind as the new key and sum values in group:

```
var aggByYearAndKind = 
  byDateAndKind.ResampleEquivalence(
  (k) => Tuple.Create(k.Item1.Year, k.Item2),
  (g) => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Value).Sum());

aggByYearAndKind.Print();
```

This will print a series that maps `2020, "A"` to `2` and also `2020, "B"` to `2`.

**EDIT** You are right - this does not seem to work. I was able to get it to work using `GroupBy` instead of `ResampleEquvialence`:

```
var dailyProfit2 =
  ts.GroupBy(kvp =>
    new { Date = new DateTime(kvp.Value.CloseDate.Year, kvp.Value.CloseDate.Month, kvp.Value.CloseDate.Day), Kind = kvp.Value.Pair })
    .SelectValues(g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.ProfitPercentage).Values.Sum());
      
// backtest_worst_day = min(daily_profit)
var worstDay2 = dailyProfit2.Min();
// backtest_best_day = max(daily_profit)
var bestDay2 = dailyProfit2.Max();
// winning_days = sum(daily_profit > 0)
var winningDays2 = dailyProfit2.Where(x => x.Value > 0).Values.Sum();
// draw_days = sum(daily_profit == 0)
var drawDays2 = dailyProfit2.Where(x => x.Value == 0).Values.Sum();
// losing_days = sum(daily_profit < 0)
var losingDays2 = dailyProfit2.Where(x => x.Value < 0).Values.Sum();
```

Comment: I just tested it. It throws `System.ArgumentException: 'Duplicate key '(11/1/2020 12:00:00 AM, "BTCUSDT")'. Duplicate keys are not allowed in the index. (Parameter 'keys')'` on `ResampleEquivalence`. The problem is that ResampleEquivalence returns only `Series<DateTime, x>`.

Comment: You can test it by adding two identical dates to your input.

Comment: @nop - Yeah, that's exactly what my comment in the question (_"In fact, you can get into trouble earlier in your code if you had duplicate dates!"_) points out. I'll add more info to the answer.

Comment: Actually, I think I do not completely understand what leads to this. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. some small code snippet with inline input data that I can actually run? The issue here is that series does not allow duplicate keys - but I'm not sure why you would be getting that. I think it must be happening _before_ you use `ResampleEquivalence`, but I don't see where.

Comment: Provided it upon my question. The idea is that I have data which has same DateTimes but that's for the different pairs, which is fine, because the pair is the actual key. Then I'm creating series with .ToOrdinalSeries()

Comment: @nop - Thanks for the edit - but I'm still unsure how this fits with the rest. Can you edit it so that it shows some initial data for `_backtestResults` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RJaS5g1e - code. https://ufile.io/a08gx8vc - json file. I kinda can't paste it on pastebin cuz it's too long

Comment: @nop - Sorry, but that's a bit too complex for me to try. Could you create some new fake small sample dataset that fits in your question here and illustrates the issue? Presumably, you just need a few rows with some duplicates, so it should not need a big JSON file.

Comment: In that case, use what I posted in the question as input data. It's the same. I have a sequence which is resampled by a DateTime. There are duplicate DateTimes in my sequence, because we can have 1/1/2021 for TRX/USDT pair and 1/1/2021 for BTC/USDT, etc. It explains those duplicate DateTimes, because they are filtered by the pair.

Comment: @nop - Then my answer should work - create an ordinal series, then use `ResampleEquivalence`, but rather then returning `DateTime` as the new key, return a tuple `Tuple<DateTime, string>` with the date and the kind...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XLbR4Qo.png https://i.imgur.com/dnjmeex.png It is exactly like that and still. Looks like it still recognizes the DateTime as an index, even tho it's a compound key

Comment: @nop - I think the issue may be with `SelectKeys` - are you sure that does not produce some duplicate keys? You could drop that call and instead use the indexing that you had in your original question.

Comment: I added a complete example with simple data. It takes the JSON data automatically from https://pastebin.com/raw/Dhp9202f. I left only 7 elements. You can test easily.

Comment: @nop - Thanks - see edit. I'm not quite sure what's wrong, but have an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That's exactly what I was using instead of the Deedle code which was broken. But the results don't match. https://i.imgur.com/yvFBnzi.png https://i.imgur.com/utIeQJG.png. It should basically group the dates by day, but idk what Deedle does